# why do we need to measure the “size” before we can integrate functions?

Tags: measure-theory

this [post](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/lecture-notes/18125_lec1.pdf) says

> We need to know how to measure the “size” or “volume” of subsets of a
>   space X before we can integrate functions f : X → R or f : X → C.

why do we need to measure the “size” before we can integrate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitive version: Consider the function $f(x) = 1$. Then integrating the function is *actually* measuring the size or volume of whatever part of $X$ you're integrating over. So if that is something that doesn't make sense in your space $X$, then you can't integrate.

A more rigorous version depends on how you define integrals, and in particular what $dx$ means to you. In some interpretations, by definition, that *is* the size measurement on $X$, so you really can't integrate without it (in particular, the measure theoretic / probability theoretic version of integration). In other integral interpretations the connection isn't quite as obvious, but it is just as necessary.